# How to pass string value to ajax in PHP & Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

i need to show different values only in drop down list.drop down list selection based result cal in ajax and display the related data show below in the drop down list.

How to pass the string value to ajax in this script.

Anyone pls guide me

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <script>
function showUser(str) {
  if (str=="") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-12 columns">
        <h1></h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-12 columns">
        <!--Main Tab Start-->
        <?php
        $res=mysql_query("select DISTINCT tag,id from password");

        if($res === false )
        {
            die(mysql_error());
        }
        ?>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <select name="tagg" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
            <option value="">Select Accounts</option>
        <?php
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {
            $dess=$row['tag'];
            $id=$row['id'];
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $id;?>"><?php echo $dess; ?></option>

            <?php
        }

        ?>
                    </select>
            </form>
             <div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>
        <!--Main Tab Ent-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Getuser.php**

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);
$result=mysql_query("select * from password WHERE id = '".$q."'");
if($result === false )
{
    die(mysql_error());
}
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $desss=$row['tag'];
}
$res=mysql_query("select * from password WHERE tag = '".$desss."'");
if($res === false )
{
    die(mysql_error());
}
?>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Id</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>username</th>
<th>Password</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Link</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<?php

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    $id=$row['id'];
     $name=$row['name'];
    $url=$row['url'];
    $uname=$row['username'];
    $pass=$row['password'];
    $tag=$row['tag'];
    $des=$row['description'];

    ?>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $uname; ?></td>
    <td><span data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" class="has-tip" title="<?php echo $pass; ?>">View</span></td>
    <td><span data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" class="has-tip" title="<?php echo $des; ?>">Description</span></td>
    <td><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" title="<?php echo $name; ?>" target="_blank">Link</a></td>

    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <?php

}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: what problem you are facing?? your code seems to be fine

Comment: i need help how to pass the option value in string in this script . My script does not work to pass the string values .only work for int values.

Comment: Stop using MySQL it is **deprecated**, use instead MySQLi or PDO. Plain MySQL has security flaws and is no longer maintained - avoid it!!

Comment: @ Martin: Hi pls guide me you mention your security tips. i am a beginner.

Comment: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have run your code, it is working fine.There is only one problem ,if you want to pass string then change following code on your `gestuser.php` 
change

```
$q = intval($_GET['q']);
```

to

```
$q =($_GET['q']);
```

and change

```
<option value="<?php echo $id;?>"><?php echo $dess; ?></option>
```

to

```
<option value="<?php echo $dess;?>"><?php echo $dess; ?></option>
```

Other wise your code is working

Comment: @Gobinath: I hope you didn't take this advice - removing `intval()` will introduce a second SQL injection vulnerability into your code.

Comment: @Sourabh: can you fix this security problem in your answer? I suggest `mysql_real_escape_string()` here, even though - as the OP is aware - the library is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your function as following and see what string you are passing through ajax

```
function showUser(str) {
    alert(str);
      if (str=="") {
```

Comment: Hi , i have copied getuser.php pls guide me

Comment: @amrita this is not an answer.. this should be posted as a comment.. you can read further here for how to write an answer in stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @NishantSolanki: I need 50 reputation to add a comment dats why

Comment: @AmritaGupta oh ok.. but if you will post comments as answers than someone will downvote it and you will loose your reputations instead of gaining it :D, best luck ..

Comment: @Amrita Gupta :  Hi i try , i got an "int" value in alert box. i need help how to pass the string value to ajax

Comment: @GobinathMahalingam: Is it the value of $id that you have passed ?

Comment: @GobinathMahalingam: <option value="<?php echo $dess;?>"><?php echo $dess; ?></option>

Comment: @GobinathMahalingam I strongly feel that you are usiing ajax too early.. you first need to clear corephp basic concepts..

Answer (score 0):

the javascript ajax function fires when the select value has changed

```
<select name="tagg" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
```

now `this.value` means **you are passing the selected value to the javascript function**

```
<option value="<?php echo $id;?>"><?php echo $dess; ?></option>
```

you have to put string in your `value` attribute

something like

```
<option value="<?php echo 'YOUR STRING HERE';?>"><?php echo $dess; ?></option>
```

now in your `getuser.php` file your query is

```
"select * from password WHERE id = '".$q."'"
```

so you will have to change the query respectively

Comment: Hi , i try to pass the string in option value but ajax cal not working only working for integer.

Comment: as said by @Amrita  what are you getting in alert box??

Comment: Hi , i  got an string value in alert box following your steps. but "getuser.php" i am try to echo the alert box value . now the value is "0" for all the drop down list selection.